# Community of R' Menachem Elon

Tags: rabbis, orthodox, authority

Rabbi Menachem Elon is described all over the web as an "Orthodox Rabbi." However, while he seems to be very respected in the academic world, I have been unable to find a single record of R' Elon interacting with the Orthodox world. Was Rabbi Elon recognized as an authority by any Orthodox community?

Comment: He learned in Yeshivat Chevron for 8 years and received semichah from Mandatory Palestine’s chief rabbis.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ‘recognized as an authority’. His role was as as a judge and jurist, not a rabbi.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Elon

Comment: Joel K, he wrote works on Jewish law so it's relevant to know if any Orthodox community considers his Halachic positions authoritative

Comment: I believe R' Yona Reiss mentions him in this shiur. https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/1008191/rabbi-yona-reiss/beis-din-arkaos/

Comment: https://www.torahmusings.com/2013/02/justice-menachem-elon-%D7%96%D7%A6%D7%9C/